# How to get the path associated to a favorite in Finder?

Tags: finder

I have some favorites in Finder (10.11.4) and I can't open some of them:

> "Folder name" can't be opened because the original item can't be found.

The folder can't be open because it is on an unmount volume. The problem is I don't know what is this volume and I would like to know the path associated to this favorite. I can't get this information with right click on the favorite, it is not listed in the Finder preferences and the information is not present in the plist file.

Where can I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the original location of an unmounted folder you've added to the Favorites Sidebar, just select the item and press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> for *Get Info*.  Alternatively, you can right click it and select the menu item.

The location will be identified in the "Where" field.

In the picture below, I took a random folder (this one named "Music Archive") and attached it to my Favorites in the Sidebar.  I then unmounted it and "got info on it."

[image]

An easier way to accomplish this (if you are using external drives) is to make use of the tags field near the top of the *Get Info* dialog box.  See [How to Keep Track of External Drives](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320946/how-to-keep-track-of-external-hard-drives) for further details.

Comment: I can't select a favorite if it is not found (or unmount). Indeed, when I click on it, I directly have the error dialog and I'm redirected to the previous location I was. Also, if I right click on it, I don't the "Get Info" option.

Comment: I've tested this with an unmounted USB drive and it works as described.